# Allowing apache to write with iptables

Tags: iptables, apache-2.2

Since to days ago I'm receiving DDOS atacks in my server. I've installed mod_evasive in apache and it works right! It writes the log and send the email with de IPs.

But there's a problem: Apache doesn't add the DROP rule in iptables (or at least it doesn't appear)

I'm using apache in Plesk, the configuration file is like:

```
DOSHashTableSize 3097
DOSPageCount 1 
DOSSiteCount 50
DOSPageInterval 1
DOSSiteInterval 1
DOSBlockingPeriod 600
DOSSystemCommand "sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s %s -j DROP"
DOSEmailNotify "xxx@xxx.com"
DOSLogDir "/var/log/evasive/"
```

Here is my 'sudoers' file:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s [0-9.]* -j DROP
```

But that doesn't help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing apache to run iptables with root privilege sounds like a very bad idea - I presume you've got root access. If it were me I'd be using a proxy program (like fail2ban) to sift the logs and write the rules.

> I've write in visudo this:

And have you checked that is what has been deployed to /etc/sudoers?

From the man page:

> If a Cmnd has associated command line arguments, then the arguments in
>         the Cmnd must match exactly those given by the user on the command line
>        (or match the wildcards if there are any)

You've used a regex rather than wildcards. Try:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables -A INPUT --dport 80 -s * -j DROP
```

Although a better idea would be to wrap the functionality in a script rather than calling iptables directly.
(note I've explicitly set the port to avoid you locking yourself out - I presume you've got ssh access).

Answer (score 2):

In "`visudo`", change ALL to root, and skip the arguments for iptables:

```
apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/iptables
```

Make sure the leading `apache` is the name of the user running the web server. (Check with `ps -ef|egrep -e 'apache|http'`

Then change your `DOSSystemCommand` to

```
DOSSystemCommand "sudo -u root /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s %s -j DROP"
```

Better solution: make a script owned by root that no one else can modify, make that script run iptables, and have apache call that script (enable that script instead of iptables in sudo).