# sudoers syntax to run shell script as php user?

Tags: sudo

I want to run

- a shell script `restore`
- as postgres user
- from php script (the user name is `php`)
- using sudo (so password is not required)

the script will have few lines of code, something like

```
dropdb <database name>
psql -c "create database <database name> with encoding 'unicode';" -U edutemplate1
psql -d <database name> -f edu.hourly.sql
```

- what would be the **sudo command syntax** to run the script `restore`
- what would be the **sudoers syntax** to allow php user to run `restore` script as `postgres` user?
- Sudo version 1.7.2p7
- Linux testing 2.6.34-12-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2010-06-29 02:39:08 +0200 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

## UPDATE

the first part of the question was already answered on SO [sudoers-syntax-to-run-shell-script-as-php-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453916/sudoers-syntax-to-run-shell-script-as-php-user)

## UPDATE2

I added `php ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/id` to /etc/sudoers and then did `su php` and then `sudo -su postgres /usr/bin/id` but I am asked for postgres' password. If I issue the same sudo command under the user root I will get correct output 'uid=26(postgres) gid=26(postgres) groups=26(postgres)'

## UPDATE3

updating sudoers to `php ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD: ALL` makes it work ...

Comment: You want `sudo -u postgres /usr/bin/id`, not `-su`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/250258/allowing-apache-to-write-with-iptables/250272#250272) for a similar scenario.

This goes in `/etc/sudoers`:

`php ALL=(postgres) NOPASSWD: /the/restore/script`

And you make php issue a command like this: `sudo -u postgres /the/restore/script`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from root "su $USERNAME -c "command"" anyway you can do it VIA sudo as well, if You can please describe what You wanna do exactly? For example from which user? is it require password? (you can define it in /etc/sudoers) By "php user" You mean www-data, or nobody or other user?

Comment: I need to run `restore` shell script from my php script. The php user's name is php. So I guess I need to sudo to run the 'restore' script as different user than 'php' user. I do not know what would be the sudoers syntaxt to I can call `exec("sudo -su postgres -S '/scripts/restore'", $output);` from my php script

Comment: exec("sudo -su php....");
But by default sudo will ask for the password for the account that You wanna use, so You can use some "expect" script first ;)

Comment: I don't know what `some "expect" script first` means. What I understood is that I can use sudo without password if the `correct line` is in sudoers. The question I asked here is how the line should look like so I can use sudo without the password...